# How can I select a value from one row in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

So I have a table:

```
place_id | name   | description      | availableDirections   
1        | Room   | A nice room      | N, W, E, S    
2        | Office | A messy office   | N, W, E, S
```

How can I get the description of only one of the rows? Would it look something like this?

```
SELECT description FROM place WHERE place.place_id="1"
```

So far, this query isn't working for me in SQL Server.

Comment: By default values in double quotes are treated as object names, this looks like an integer so wouldn't need any quotes at all.

Comment: The error for using `"` explains what is wrong - `"` is *not* the string delimiter. The string delimiter is the single quote: `'`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos it can be a string delimiter if `quoted_identifier` is off.

Comment: @MartinSmith doing this will create compatiblity problems. It should *not* be used.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I haven't recommended its use. Just adding relevant information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT description FROM place WHERE place_id = 1
```

Comment: That's not the cause of the problem. SQL Server will convert the string value `1` to an int before searching. The real problem is that `"` is used for *object names*

Comment: @bluemunch by using `"1"` you should get a *syntax* error. `"` is used for table and column names, similar to `[]`

Comment: @bluemunch `SELECT * FROM place` in same query window give you this rows?

Comment: @RuslanK. Yes it returns nothing surprisingly.

Comment: @bluemunch maybe you do not commited INSERT?

Comment: They are prepopulated rows. Why would I have to INSERT if they already exist?